# How can I send email with template using the cell value as recipients?

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I want to send an email using a template (oft file) and using the cell value (start from k9 to last cell which has value) as the recipients. There is no error when I press run but the emails were not sent out.

If I remove the below part of the code, the email can be sent but only for 1 cell's value:

```
dim i as integer
dim lastrow as integer

lastrow = application.worksheetfunction.counta(ws.range("k:k"))

for i = 9 to lastrow

next i
```

If I remove the above 5 line code and set the `sendid = ws.range("k9").value`, the macro can run and the email can be sent,

```
enSub sumit()
 
    Dim SendID
    Dim Subject
    Dim Body
    Dim otlapp As Object
    Dim olMail As Object
    Dim olMail1 As Object
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim lastrow As Integer
    Dim ws As Object
 
    Set otlapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set olMail = otlapp.CreateItemFromTemplate("\\cpadm001.corp.ocalwa.com\clk\DEPT\CLKDEPT6\IMT\SAO\SSC\Team\Team1\Script\IT Services.oft")
    Set olMail1 = otlapp.CreateItemFromTemplate("\\cpadm001.corp.ocalwa.com\clk\DEPT\CLKDEPT6\IMT\SAO\SSC\Team\Team1\Script\Email Policy.oft")
 
    Set doc = olMail.GetInspector.WordEditor
    Set doc1 = olMail1.GetInspector.WordEditor
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Send Letters")
 
    vTemplateBody = olMail.HTMLBody
    vTemplateBody1 = olMail1.HTMLBody
 
    Subject = "Introduction to IT Services"
    Subject1 = "Corporate Email Policy"
    HTMLBody = vTemplateBody
    HTMLBody1 = vTemplateBody1
 
    lastrow = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Range("k:k"))
 

    For i = 9 To lastrow
 
        SendID = ws.Range("k" & i).Value
     
        With olMail
            .SentOnBehalfOfName = "ITSC@ocalwa.com"
            .To = SendID
            If CCID <> "" Then
              .CC = CCID
            End If
           
            .Subject = Subject
         
            Set WrdRng = doc.Range
            WrdRng.Paste
            .Send
     
        End With
     
        With olMail1
            .SentOnBehalfOfName = "ITSC@ocalwa.com"
            .To = SendID
            If CCID <> "" Then
              .CC = CCID
            End If
           
            .Subject = Subject1
         
            Set WrdRng = doc1.Range
            WrdRng.Paste
            .Send
        End With
 
    Next i
 
End Sub
```

Comment: .To = .To & ";" & SendID

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to include the part creating your mail in the loop as well, it looks to me like the mail is sent to the first recipient only and then there is no object left - don't know how to describe better.

Try the following after your declearations:

```
lastrow = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Range("k:k"))

For i = 9 To lastrow
    Set otlapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set olMail = otlapp.CreateItemFromTemplate("\\cpadm001.corp.ocalwa.com\clk\DEPT\CLKDEPT6\IMT\SAO\SSC\Team\Team1\Script\IT Services.oft")
    Set olMail1 = otlapp.CreateItemFromTemplate("\\cpadm001.corp.ocalwa.com\clk\DEPT\CLKDEPT6\IMT\SAO\SSC\Team\Team1\Script\Email Policy.oft")
    Set doc = olMail.GetInspector.WordEditor
    Set doc1 = olMail1.GetInspector.WordEditor
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Send Letters")

    vTemplateBody = olMail.HTMLBody
    vTemplateBody1 = olMail1.HTMLBody
    Subject = "Introduction to IT Services"
    Subject1 = "Corporate Email Policy"
    HTMLBody = vTemplateBody
    HTMLBody1 = vTemplateBody1
    SendID = ws.Range("k" & i).Value
    With olMail
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = "ITSC@ocalwa.com"
        .To = SendID

        If CCID <> "" Then
            .CC = CCID
        End If

        .Subject = Subject
        Set WrdRng = doc.Range
        WrdRng.Paste
        .Send
    End With

    With olMail1
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = "ITSC@ocalwa.com"
        .To = SendID
        If CCID <> "" Then
            .CC = CCID
        End If

        .Subject = Subject1

        Set WrdRng = doc1.Range
        WrdRng.Paste
        .Send
    End With
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate rather than overwrite if there are to be multiple addresses in one mail.

```
.To = .To & ";" & SendID
```

CountA may be trickier to use than implemented.

```
' If rows 1 to 8 are empty
lastrow = 8 + Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Range("k:k"))
Debug.Print " lastrow where rows 1 to 8 are empty : " & lastrow
```